# Does SetScrollInfo() hide the scroll bar if SIF_DISABLENOSCROLL is set?

Tags: c, windows, winapi

If I have a top level window with built in scroll bars, and the horizontal scroll bar has SIF_DISABLENOSCROLL set, and if I size the window vertically to a smaller size, will `SetScrollInfo()` hide the horizontal scroll bar if the client area height is smaller than the horizontal scroll bar height?

Answer (score 1):

From Windows Help in VC2005:

> This value is used only when setting a scroll bar's parameters. If the scroll bar's new parameters make the scroll bar unnecessary, disable the scroll bar instead of removing it.

It seems to imply a "yes" to your question: the scroll bar will only be shown when necessary.

Comment: I think that is talking about disabling, which is different from hiding

Comment: @Rm32a, I see... Then he should use the `ShowScrollBar` function to remove the scroll bar, however, that function will not automatically re-show the scroll bar when the window's content extends below or above the window.